# Itertools permutation with OR operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Given a `list` of `strings`, I want to return all possible permutations where the strings may contain an OR operator.

How can I do this? A pointer to which functions I should use is ok (with code will be helpful, but not required).

For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import itertools

list_of_strings = ['a|b', 'c']

# I probably need to add some '|' splitter here

for permutation in itertools.permutations(list_of_strings, 2):
    print(''.join(str(word) for word in permutation))
```

prints

```
a|bc
ca|b
```

but I want

```
ac
bc
ca
cb
```

That is, using either 'a' or 'b', but not both.

There may be multiple strings strings with '|'. For example, `list_of_strings = ['a|b', 'c', 'd|e']`.

There may be multiple ORs within a string. For example, `list_of_strings = ['a|b|d|e', 'c']`.

The previous example should print

```
ac
bc
dc
ec
ca
cb
cd
ce
```

The strings may be longer than one character. For example, `list_of_strings = ['race', 'car|horse']`.

The output should be

```
racecar
racehorse
carrace
horserace
```

Comment: There was an answer that words, but gives duplicated results. `def perm(s, n=2):
    for p in itertools.product(*[k.split("|") for k in s]):
        yield from itertools.permutations(p, n)`. With `perm(['a|b', 'c', 'd|e'])`, `['a', 'c']` is duplicated. In my case, I could generate the file with all permutations and use `sort` and `uniq` to remove duplicates.

Comment: Would you mind try to use my answer and see if it suits your needs?

Comment: @Sanyash Yes, your code is more efficient than creating the file and then sorting. I've added a comment to your post to fit my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are just a few steps.

1. Split each of your original strings on `|` to get lists of strings.
2. Compute the permutations of your list of lists of strings.
3. Compute the product of each permutation
4. Join each element of those products with the null string.

Using the `itertools` and `operator` modules, it looks like this:

```
>>> from itertools import product, permutations
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> splitter = methodcaller("split", "|")
>>> list_of_strings = ["a|b", "c", "foo|bar"]
>>> strings = ["".join(y) for x in permutations(map(splitter, list_of_strings)) for y in product(*x)]
>>> for s in strings:
...   print(s)
...
acfoo
acbar
bcfoo
bcbar
afooc
abarc
bfooc
bbarc
cafoo
cabar
cbfoo
cbbar
cfooa
cfoob
cbara
cbarb
fooac
foobc
barac
barbc
fooca
foocb
barca
barcb
```

The long line more readably is

```
strings = ["".join(y) 
             for x in permutations(map(splitter, list_of_strings))
             for y in product(*x)]
```

If you are not as prone to using `map` as I usually am, you can get rid of `methodcaller` and use a generator expression for the argument to `permutations`.

```
strings  = ["".join(z)
             for y in permutations(x.split("|") for x in list_of_strings)
             for z in product(*y)]
```

Comment: Cool! And generator expression will make it even a one-liner.

Comment: This is even more efficient and clear than the other correct answer!

Comment: For future readers, remember to use `permutations(..., n)` for large lists if you only want a permutation that only uses n elements from the list.

Comment: There's no need for a second argument to `permutations`; I'm computing the permutations of a list constructed from the original list of strings, which means you want all permutations.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution with two stages:

1. generate permutations of `list_of_strings`
2. recursively parse `or` operators

Have a look, seems to pass all your test cases, feel free to ask clarification in comments.

```
import itertools


def permutations_with_ors(list_of_strings):
    for item in itertools.permutations(list_of_strings):
        yield from parse_ors(item)


def parse_ors(tuple_of_strings):
    for i, string in enumerate(tuple_of_strings):
        if '|' in string:
            for item in string.split('|'):
                replaced = (
                    tuple_of_strings[:i] + 
                    (item,) + 
                    tuple_of_strings[i + 1:]
                )
                yield from parse_ors(replaced)
            break
    else:
        yield ''.join(tuple_of_strings)


list_of_strings = ['a|b', 'c']

for item in permutations_with_ors(list_of_strings):
   print(item)

# output:
# ac
# bc
# ca
# cb

print()

list_of_strings = ['a|b|d|e', 'c']

for item in permutations_with_ors(list_of_strings):
   print(item)

# output:
# ac
# bc
# dc
# ec
# ca
# cb
# cd
# ce

print()

list_of_strings = ['a|b', 'c', 'd|e']

for item in permutations_with_ors(list_of_strings):
   print(item)

# output is quite long, please check it yourself

print()

list_of_strings = ['race', 'car|horse']

for item in permutations_with_ors(list_of_strings):
   print(item)

# output:
# racecar
# racehorse
# carrace
# horserace
```

Comment: I just tested this real data and forgot to mention that the strings may be longer than one character. I have added an example case in the post.

Comment: Updated my answer, now it passes the test case you added.

Comment: For anyone wondering, replace `''.join` in  `else: yield ''.join(tuple_of_strings)` with `'A'.join` to have "A" separate the original entries

Comment: I'm also using `for item in itertools.permutations(list_of_strings, n):` to create permutations of length n.